# On existence of other physical constants and the assumption in proof for special theory of relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, physical-constants

The only constant (that exist in the world) is speed of light in vacuum or c which is close to 3X10^8 m/s so 'all other constants should be variables (to some degree) w.r.t. this constant'. If this is true than why are other constants mentioned in the Physics texts, such as h(plank's constant), e(charge on an electron), ε(permittivity of charge in free space), 0 K(-273.15 C or absolute Zero temperature) etc. are not dependent on c?

Comment: Where did you find that quote?

Comment: Since "c is the only constant" as per special theory of relativity so all other constants must be variables under 'specific set of conditions' such as length, mass, velocity etc. so the quote is evident.

Comment: If appears that you made up a quote and attributed it to Einstein. That helps to explains why it is completely wrong.

Comment: In natural units, $c=1$. It doesn't make sense to talk about whether or not something depends on 1. 1 isn't a variable.

Comment: What are natural units? Do you mean dimensions ?

Comment: @user240988 false attribution is not acceptable. I will remove the false attribution, please do not do that in the future

Comment: @user240988: Natural units means units in which $c=1$ by definition. People doing relativity normally use such units.

Comment: "so all other constants must be variables [...] such as length, mass, velocity etc." - none of those are universal constants. I guess your question is how come there are these other constants that are universal and not observer-dependent?

Comment: Please do not edit an old question to ask a completely different question, but ask a new question instead if you have another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only constant (that exist in the world) is speed of light in vacuum or c which is close to 3X10^8 m/s so 'all other constants should be variables (to some degree) w.r.t. this constant'. If this is true than why are other constants mentioned in the Physics texts

The fact that other constants are mentioned indicates that the initial premise is false. It is simply not true that c is the only constant.